# Update control asynchronously

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, synchronous, multithreading

I've been reading over the internet how to solve the problem of updating controls from different threads than the one that contains the control and also read "Pro VB 2010 and the .Net 4.0 Platform" and I start to wonder. Is the following code performing in synchronous fashion?

```
Private Sub SaveData(ByVal filepath As String)
   If InvokeRequired Then
      Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf SaveData))
   Else
      ... the actual code
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm confused.  What's your actual question?

Comment: You want to know if this code can run with multiple threads using it without problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends widely on your calling context.

If you are calling it from the UI thread or your main thread, then yes it will function synchronously.

If you call it from a thread that is not your UI or main thread, then it is going to function asynchronously to your UI or main thread, but synchronously with the calling thread, waiting until the UI or main thread is done processing the delegate.

So it can go both ways. It can operate synchronously and asynchronously. I think what you are missing is that the code itself does not preform in a synchronous or asynchronous fashion, the execution of the code is either synchronous or asynchronous.

The reason why you make an update function:

```
Private Sub UpdateLabel(byval tLabel as Label, byval Value as String)
    If tLabel.Invokerequired Then
         Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf UpdateLabel)
    Else
        tLabel.Text = Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Is so that you can call it whenever you want to change the text, without having to worry about a cross thread exception.

This method would be safe to call from the UI thread during a click event and it would also be safe to call from a along running background thread, because the change would still only ever be made on the UI or Main thread. You use code like this to ensure synchronicity with your changes to controls owned by other threads.

This style of updating is meant to synchronize your changes and avoid cross threading.

Answer (score 0):

The `Invoke` method is a synchronous call that will block the calling thread until the delegate finishes executing on the UI thread.

If you want to calling thread to continue immediately (before the code on the UI thread runs), call `BeginInvoke()`, which is asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a little old, but here's a modification of Pow-Ian's answer that worked for me.

```
Private Sub UpdateLabel(ByVal tControl As Control, ByVal Value As String)
    If tControl.InvokeRequired Then
        tControl.Invoke(Sub() tControl.Text = Value)
    Else
        tControl.Text = Value
    End If
End Sub
```

This should work to change the text for any control using the UI thread, even if it is called from an async method.